# Active Directory AND integrated user store on ArcGIS Server 10.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, license, security

We have one License for ArcGIS Server 10.2.

We need to publish Services for internal use with Active Directory authentication and for external use (internet) with username/password authentication.

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Is it possible to create two sites with one AGS License on one server so that I can use different user-stores?

Comment: Interested to read beefed up answer from @simon.  My understanding is ags only allows one security model. It would require a seperate license to seperate the security as such.  However I use geocortex which does allow multiple security models. All services are secured in ags with ad. Sites are configured for identity store and or enterprise security at the site level in geocortex.

Comment: Were you able to find any more information on this?  I am trying to use a similar scenario.

Comment: @SethP: Two Sites with one License is not possible. We use multiple WebAdapters now. One is only reachable from the Internet, the others are internal. The WebAdaptor, that faces the internet, performs a mapping from "external"-Usernames to internal ArcGIS Server users. It's not perfect, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Its late, so ill beef this answer up over next couple of days.
Make use of two web adapters (fine with one license).
Ill add more details later.

[image]

Comment: Did you have anything more to add on this?

Comment: Been bit short of time - Should I delete and re-answer when I can provide more substantial info?

Comment: Up to you of course, but I think you should leave what you have for now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to "add comment" to Simon's answer, so adding this as another answer:

Looks like Simon's slide is from this [ArcGIS for Server Deployment Scenarios talk](http://video.esri.com/watch/3299/arcgis-for-server-deployment-scenarios), at around 25 minutes in.
Also, [Supporting a mix of public and private services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Supporting_a_mix_of_public_and_private_services/01540000067v000000/) is mentioned in the talk.